# PHP If Else Statement with PHP Include

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax, include

how do you create an if else statement that contains an include statement?

In ASP you need to have the double quotes but I am not sure how to do it in PHP.

I believe the issue lies with this:

```
<?php include 'i_main-nav-wohl.php' ?>
```

I Tried the following:

```
    <?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if (strpos($url, "/occupational/wohl/") === 0) {
    echo '<?php include ''i_main-nav-wohl.php'' ?>';
    }  else {
    echo '<?php include ''i_main-nav-wohl.php'' ?>';
    }
    ?>



    <?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if (strpos($url, "/occupational/wohl/") === 0) {
    echo '<?php include "'i_main-nav-wohl.php'" ?>';
    }  else {
    echo '<?php include "'i_main-nav-wohl.php'" ?>';
    }
    ?>



    <?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if (strpos($url, "/occupational/wohl/") === 0) {
    echo '<?php include 'i_main-nav-wohl.php' ?>';
    }  else {
    echo '<?php include 'i_main-nav-wohl.php' ?>';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You seem to include the same file no matter what, so why even bother to `if`?

Comment: I am not including the same file, it just looks like it in this code. I was just testing and did not copy it over. And @Dagon, that is good advice, do you have a resource that may help? Keep in mind that I am still learning. That is why I come to this site. We have to start somewhere.

Comment: @JHP i suggest starting here:http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Echoing in php means that it displays in the browser and does not implement itself.  Just set the `include` directly in the if statement instead of echoing it.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't echo php tag in php code .

If you want your php code to be executed by your server,

Instead of this code :

```
echo '<?php include ''i_main-nav-wohl.php'' ?>';
```

just do this :

```
include 'i_main-nav-wohl.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a second php tag within your if-else-statement. Otherhwise your PHP output will result in a PHP document containing the content of your if or else branch.

Thus, if you want to produce conditional HTML or CSS use echo. Otherwhise just write your PHP commands without additional php tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like that :

```
<?php 

$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if (strpos($url, "/occupational/wohl/") === 0) {
    include 'i_main-nav-wohl.php';
}  else {
    include 'i_main-nav-wohl.php';
}
?>
```

Or even better :

```
<?php 

$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$fileToInclude = strpos($url, "/occupational/wohl/") === 0 ? 'i_main-nav-wohl.php' : 'i_main-nav-wohl.php';

include($fileToInclude);

?>
```

BTW you are including the same file in both cases.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have learned some more and was able to get it to work! Really appreciate the help. (Also, I am not actually pulling in the same file, I just gt an error when I started writing the code (copy and paste the php file name) so I just pasted it like that here) Again thanks so much!